# How to get date to ISOString with GMT timezone

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, momentjs, toisostring

I get date

```
Fri Dec 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (East Kazakhstan Time)
```

But when I convert to ISOString I get

```
2019-12-19T18:00:00.000Z
```

and I guess this convert does not consider timezone..

Also I tried convert with moment-timezone & same result.

```
moment("Fri Dec 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (East Kazakhstan Time)").tz('Asia/Bishkek').toISOString()
```

If I get **date with timezone** I should **convert with timezone**: 
I **should get**

```
2019-12-20T00:00:00.000Z
```

**not**

```
2019-12-19T18:00:00.000Z
```

If I'm not right and I make a mistake correct me

## UPDATED

I found solution which solves my problem

```
moment(this.data.start.getTime() - this.data.start.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000).toISOString()
```

which convert from GMT +0 to GMT +6 timezone

 And now new question:

 How to make more simple above code using momentjs.. Or this is enough?

Comment: This changes the date to represent a time 6 hours later than it should, i.e. you are fundamentally changing the moment in time that the date represents.

Answer (score 1):

> I get date Fri Dec 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (East Kazakhstan Time) But when I convert to ISOString I get 2019-12-19T18:00:00.000Z

The timestamps represent exactly the same moment in time. There is no error here.

> If I get date with timezone I should convert with timezone. I should get 2019-12-20T00:00:00.000Z

No you should not. You should get 2019-12-19T18:00:00.000Z.

> If I'm not right and I make a mistake correct me

You are not right.

*toISOString* is always UTC. If you want ISO 8601 format and your local timezone, use the built–in parser and the default *moment* formatting:

```js
let s = 'Fri Dec 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (East Kazakhstan Time)';

// Built–in parser, not recommended
let d = new Date(s);
// Format with moment.js
console.log(moment(d).format());

// Modify string for parsing with moment.js
let e = s.substr(0,33).replace('GMT','');
// Parse with moment.js
let m = moment(e, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');
// Format with moment.js
console.log(m.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```